# C# SqlDataAdapter turns all values in Column of Decimal to zero

Tags: c#, sql-server, dataset

I am using SqlDataAdapter to fill a DataSet from a SQLServer table. All of the columns are filled properly except the Transaction column which is a Decimal type in the database. These values all become 0.0.

The code:

```
using (SqlConnection dbconn = new SqlConnection (connection_string)) {
            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter (query, dbconn);
            exposureSequence = new DataSet ();
            adapter.Fill (exposureSequence, "ExposureSequence");
        }
```

This code

```
            foreach(DataRow r in exposureSequence.Tables["ExposureSequence"].Rows){
            Console.WriteLine(r["TransactionAmount"] + ", ");
        }
```

prints

```
0.0000, 
0.0000, 
0.0000,
...
```

But if I do this:

```
using (IDataReader reader = dbcmd.ExecuteReader()) {
                    while(reader.Read()){
                        //int ActionClientID = (int) reader["ActionClientID"];
                        Decimal TransactionAmount = (Decimal) reader["TransactionAmount"];
                        Console.WriteLine(TransactionAmount);
                    }
```

My output is:

```
164.4950
164.4950
164.4950
...
```

Why is adapter.Fill turning the TransactionAmount values to 0.000?

Comment: did you tried to debug first code? Are you sure that dataset contains "0"?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a difference between the 2 versions of code you posted. You should receive the same results. If you execute the same query by using a dataReader or a dataAdapter the difference is how they execute and not the results you get. Do you use the same query for execution? If you do, I believe the problem maybe somewhere else (and not in the difference of the 2 versions).

Comment: That is precisely the problem... they should both work.... It is the same query for both.